# How can I call a method which has Interface as one of the parameter in C#?

Tags: c#, methods, interface, parameter-passing, interface-implementation

I have the following method (3rd party sdk method being implemented in my dll):

```
public void PlaceItem(myItemData item, IRequest request)
{
    var item = (ItemClassData)item; //**myItemData is the base class for ItemClassData**
    item.Id = 101;
    request.Succeeded(item.Id);
}
```

The interface parameter is as below:

```
public interface IRequest
{
    void Failed(string Error);
    void Succeeded(string ItemId);
}
```

I want to call this method from a function. I know how to pass an object as the first parameter when I call this method. But how do I pass the second parameter (Interface).
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a class that implements this interface like

```
public class MyClass : IRequest
{
    public void Failed(string Error) { // do something }
    public void Succeeded(string ItemId) { // do something }
}
```

create instance of it and pass it to the method

```
var inst = new MyClass();    
PlaceItem(..., inst);
```

Comment: Excellent!!! Thanks a tonn @Ondrej Janacek..! I'm still in the learning mode so please don't mind my basic questions..;-)

Comment: @aceventura I really don't mind. Everybody has to start somewhere ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass object of any class which implements that interface.

for example:

```
public class MyClass : IRequest
{
    // class definition and implementation of methods
   void Failed (string Error) {};
   void Succeeded (string ItemId) {};
}
```

Now you can pass the object of `MyClass` in that method.

```
// create an instance of MyClass
MyClass objMyClass = new MyClass();

// call the method
PlaceItem(myDataItem, objMyClass);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question @Sachin. Sorry, I have already voted.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass any implementation of `IRequest` as the second parameter.

```
public class Request : IRequest
{
    public void Failed(string Error)
    {
       //do something here
    }

    public void Succeeded(string ItemId);
    {
       //do something here
    }
}

//Calling your method
Request mySecondPara = new Request();

PlaceItem(item, mySecondPara)
```

Also you can use an IOC container ([Unity](https://unity.codeplex.com/), [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/)) to do the job. This is also known as [Dependency Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921152.aspx).

Comment: Thank You for your response @Kaf, Sorry I have already voted it. I shall take your valuable suggestion of Ninject into consideration to test it.